# Apple Recusando meu aplicativo em Phonegap

Tags: ios, app, apple

Abaixo segue a mensagem da Apple

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Your app still crashed on iPhone and iPad￼ running iOS 12.3￼ on WiFi when we tapped the "take a photo or video" button in the chat section.￼

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure that it runs as expected.

Resources

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please review Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports.

Vocês sabem me dizer o que posso fazer para realizar esse acerto ?

Comment: É só traduzir essa mensagem... Estão falando que o app está fechando sozinho quando estão clicando no botão "take a photo or video". Você precisa corrigir esse erro e reenviar o app.

Comment: Pior que eu já testei e está funcionando perfeitamente no Iphone e Ipad..

Comment: Também ja tive um problema assim. Funcionava nos meus testes e lá dava algum bug. Recompilei como uma nova versão, sem alterar nada nos códigos, enviei de novo para eles e passou.